# windows 10 mouse not working intermittently tried all solutions still not working

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

So I am a tech, but this has me stumped, I have a client that has a windows 10 HP touchscreen all in one pc. but her mouse intermittently stops working, they have replaced the mouse, tried different usb ports, reinstalled mouse driver, did all updates, even updated to the latest windows 10 release. after a restart the mouse worked for a few hours but then today its stopped working again. light is on its getting power, system says the mouse is connected but no movement... you cant see the pointer on the screen at all, however everything else works keyboard etc... all other usb devices work... i am at a loss...

Comment: Bad habits for the user that let him kill a mouse in a few hours?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wireless? Try a wired mouse.
2. Could the OS be looking for another, previously used, input device? Nirsoft's free [USBDevview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) displays a list of all USB devices as stored in the Registry, and current connection status, and enables a device to be disabled, uninstalled, disconnected. You might also use *USBDevview* to remove the mouse in question, then unplugging it and plugging it back in.